# How to create Country-->State/Province--->Zip Code drop down using geonames webservice + asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, country

I'm planning to create a cascading dropdown list of Country--> State/Province--->Zip code using geonames. Do you have any good web service or examples?

Your reply is greatly appreciated,
Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://diennguyen.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/mvc-asp-net-cascading-dropdownlists/) a good example on creating cascade drop downs in MVC.  From there you'd setup the web service calls to get what you want.  You'll probably want to cache that data or provide a good singleton service to store it so you don't have the expense of multiple web service calls.